# How to see the details of crashes in Firebase Crashlytics?

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I can’t see the details of crashes from my Firebase console (Crashlytics view).

There is this default view to show the 3 steps to integrate Crashlytics:

[image]

Is there a specific setup to enable Crashlytics view?

I have used Crashlytics for 1 year and it works perfectly. I just want to migrate all my data reports into Firebase. I followed this tutorial: https://proandroiddev.com/migrating-crashlytics-to-the-firebase-console-5e05b6ff8c12

From project overview on Firebase, I can see with the crash (done yesterday for my test), and if i click on it there is the same default view.

[image]

Comment: Hey, did you find the solution? I have the same problem?

Comment: I had the same problem, but somehow, after multiple tries firebase saw my app and the crash. Really strange behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Fabric Crashlytics before?

If so, you should click the second radio button on the first step and do the linking.

On the other hand, if this is your first time doing it, try clicking the first option "Yes, this app is new to Crashlytics (it doesn't have any version of the SDK)". After choosing that option, you should do [test crashes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/force-a-crash) or it won't work.